# logging and job controls [scope] in a powershell script run via scheduled tasks

Tags: powershell, logging, scope, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a Scheduled task that executes a powershell script.

regardless, I get `log4net` output from the rest of the script.  It is when the `$job=Start-BitsTransfer` part runs that I get nothing.

If i just execute script in `PShell`, works like a champ.  The job controls/logic works and I get output.

When I run within a scheduled task, the SCRIPT scope (best I can tell from `ss64.com/ps/syntax-scopes`) doesn't output and I can't really access or control.

Here is the part of the script that is killing me:

```
$log.Info("TestPath is:" +(Test-Path $DestDir\$file))
if (!(Test-Path $DestDir\$file)) 
{
    $log.Info('COPY $SrcDir\$file - $DestDir\')
    $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Asynchronous "$SrcDir\$file" "$DestDir\$file" -DisplayName $file

    $log.Info("JUST RAN JOB")
    $log.Info("JUST RAN JOB::jobstate =" +$(Get-Job -Name $file))
    WHILE ( $job.JobState -eq 'Transferring' -or $job.JobState -eq 'Connecting' )
    {
        $log.Info("jobstate =" +$job.JobState)
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
    }
    $log.Info("jobstate= " +$job.JobState+" -- starting Complete command")
    TRY { 
        $log.Info("Completing Job= " +$job.JobState + " with ID: " +$(Get-BitsTransfer | select $_.JobID))
        Get-BitsTransfer | complete-bitstransfer 
        $log.Info("Completed Job= " +$job.JobState)
    } CATCH { 
        $log.Error("ERROR Completing Job " ) }
    }
```

closest I've come to blog/article on what I need [is here](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Task-Scheduler/) but didn't get me what I need (by warren f.) and a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243915/powershell-script-creates-empty-zip-file-when-run-automatically-through-task-sch), - [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042645/log-file-not-being-generated-while-running-a-script-via-windows-task-scheduler) when submitting this on stackoverflow, but there was no resolution...

I've tried (what I can remember trying):

- using log4net in script
- sending output to file in scheduled task config
- set-psdebug -trace
- Warren F's article (linked above)
- sending job output to file in script code

AAARRRGGGG!!
again, TIA.

njoylif

BTW, here is sample log output:

> 2016-11-09 17:06:34,222 [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO  TestPath
>   is:False 2016-11-09 17:06:34,425 [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO 
>   COPY \10.104.192.107\d$\BULocal\2016-10-30.bak - F:\BURemote\
>   2016-11-09 17:06:34,519 [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO  JUST RAN JOB
>   2016-11-09 17:06:35,207 [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO  JUST RAN
>   JOB::jobstate = 2016-11-09 17:06:35,207 [Pipeline Execution Thread]
>   INFO  jobstate=  -- starting Complete command 2016-11-09 17:06:35,238
>   [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO  Completing Job=  with ID:
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob
>   Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.BitsJob 2016-11-09
>   17:06:35,582 [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO  Completed Job=

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Nox.png)

Comment: That's a lot of text, and code that requires horizontal scrolling. Your chances of getting help will increase if you provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or the closest you can get to one).

Comment: What happens if you replace the `select $_.JobID` with `select -expand JobID`?

Comment: @mklement0 , thanks for the tip...I'm just not sure how to boil this down and get across what I need to...I'll work on that as I keep hitting my head on desk.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy, that actually game me the ID.  a thread to pull on...Thanks!